# What should I do when I am getting death threats because of this site?

Tags: discussion, support

Just before *Avengers: Infinity War*’s release date, I got an email threatening me not to post any questions about *Avengers: Infinity War* because I intentionally spoil big movies.

First, how could anyone find the email address attached to my SE account? Whenever I contact a user from this site, I use a different email address. Also, it is difficult to do social engineering because the username I use here is unique. Can Sci-Fi mods see my email address?

Second, what should I do about it? I also expect the sender of the email to clarify anonymously if he/she is reading this. Last I checked, I was accused of spoiling a movie back in 2015 and I still maintain that those were accidental, not intentional. Also, you can check in my recent questions that I put lots of efforts to hide the spoilers. If it was meant as a joke, I won't go to cyber cops.

P. S. I am not accusing a mod. It's possible he/she just shared my email to others who did this (but, even in this case, I expect CMs to punish mods for breach of privacy). Smart social engineering is yet another possibility.

Comment: are you sure you didn't confuse 'death threat' with 'moderator warning'?

Comment: oh, and of course mods can see your email address,

Comment: and if you _literally_ got a death threat in email, you should contact the appropriate authorities.

Comment: @KutuluMike A mod warning would come from a legit SE email. Also, warning to not post something doesn't match with TOS and ethics of this site.

Comment: @KutuluMike I meant Sci-Fi mods. Obviously, CMs can see my email, but they don't participate on this site.

Comment: A death threat from an SF&F mod is quite an accusation. If you can back it up and are not just spouting hyperbole, you best contact the community managers.

Comment: @SQB That's just a possibility. It's also possible that a mod shared my email to other who did this. BTW, I have already contacted CMs.

Comment: I don't think you know what "social engineering" actually means. Are you trying to say that someone doxed you?

Comment: @Mooz Yes. Revealing my email (which is confidential information) is actually what doxing means.

Answer (score 22):

If you legitimately think your PII was accessed and used irresponsibly, and you want recourse through Stack Exchange, then use the [Contact Us](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/contact) page, choose reason "Other", and explain the situation and wait for a response from the CM team to do an investigation.

If you are worried about your safety, you should look up the relevant local laws to see if what you purportedly received violates any, and then contact someone at the proper office.

If feasible, you probably want to get a new email address for your personal uses, as the current one is compromised.

I do feel like these answers are fairly obvious, and so the purpose behind your question confuses me. I'd be concerned that by posting this publicly you've elicited enough of a response from the alleged emailer to encourage them to do it again. Hence the suggestion of starting to use a new email address.

Answer (score 14):

It's impossible to guess at what's going on here with the information you've provided thus far; there are numerous ways in which someone could have obtained your email: you've been a member here for many years, under numerous usernames and avatars, and there are organizations that make it their business to compile this sort of information and cross-reference it between different services; all it takes is one slip somewhere on the 'Net and there's a good chance it ended up in *someone's* database.

But we take threats and charges of moderator malfeasance very seriously, and will investigate as far as it is feasible for us to do. Please forward us the email you received *immediately*, in its entirety as you received it, and we'll follow up with what we learn.